# C++ Find & Change Value in Map

Tags: c++, maps

I've scoured but not finding a solution; this *is* part of a homework assignment so looking more for tips/explanation than outright solution.

Problem:
I am parsing a file and extracting key elements into a map. I've declared my standard non-const map as : map<label,element>. In a second phase of the program, I am needing to locate if  exists in "map" and replace its value.

I'm able to find the element, and print it, but I can't seem to get it to change. It's not a constant, so it should be editable, but maybe I'm using the wrong function?

((For reference, i is a line number (19, current value stored in map), value_i is a stored int variable I'm trying to insert into my second element (current value is 0) ))

```
        for (auto &el : labels) {
            if (el.second == i) {
                el.second == value_i;
                std::cout << "Label " << el.first << " value changed to: " << el.second << std::endl;
            }
```

Output:
Label n value changed to: 19

Desired Ouput:
Label n value changed to: 0

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A decent compiler should give a warning for `el.second == value_i;`. And if not then you need to enable more warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made a simple mistake which is `el.second == value_i;` - you didn't assign value for `second`, you checked if its equal `value_i`. If your compiler didn't give you any warning about it, I recommend setting a higher level of warnings ( you can read online on how to do it on probably every compiler), that way you won't miss such small mistakes.

If you change this line of code to:
`el.second = value_i;`

It will do what  you desired.

Comment: Omgosh, well glad I didn’t spin for too many hours with that in my face. Smh! Thank you! I will research increasing my error checking. Thank you both!